# How to allow only few setters to set value to zero in java using conditional statements?

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm using 4 setter to allow user to set marks for 4 people as follows -

```
Marks marks = new Marks();
marks.setJames(1);
marks.setPeter(2);
marks.setRayn(3);
marks.setLayla(0);
```

**Problem Statement -**

1. I want a scenario where the user can only provide 0 marks only upto 3 people but not 4.
2. If user is trying to set 4th person with 0 marks after setting up 3 people's marks = 0 , then we need to throw an error of something like (Can't set 4 people to have 0 marks).
3. How can I achieve this? I know this maybe a silly question but I'm noob at java. Thanks in advance!

Comment: in each check the 3 others ?

Comment: A static field that is incremented every time one of the appropriate setters is called, but only if the value passed to the setter is 0 and the value of the static field is less than 3?

Comment: So your `Marks` instance is in an invalid state after creation? Don't do this.

Comment: Also the design here seems weird to me, but I don't know if you did what you did due to further restrictions in the problem statement. It makes much more sense for the marks to be an attribute of the person. Because the way you're doing it now you can set marks for James, Peter, Rayn and Layla, but you'll need to modify your code if you later on want to be able to set marks for, say, Albert or Joanna.